# Fuchsian groups and automorphisms of Riemann surfaces

Tags: fuchsian-groups, riemann-surfaces

Let $\Gamma \subseteq PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ be a Fuchsian group, possibly containing elliptic elements. Is it true that $N(\Gamma) / \Gamma$, where $N(\Gamma)$ the normalizer of $\Gamma$ in $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$, is isomorphic to the automorphism group of $\Gamma \backslash \mathcal{H}^*$?

Here, $\mathcal{H}^*$ is the union of the upper-half plane and the set of cusps of $\Gamma$.

If so, can you point me to a reference, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compact Riemann surface $\Gamma\backslash\mathcal H^*$ may have authomorphisms that do not preserve the set of points corresponding to the cusps of $\Gamma$, so I believe the answer is no.

Comment: Say, the compactified quotient could be the 2-sphere, whose group of automorphisms is $PSL(2,C)$, while the quotient $N(\Gamma)/\Gamma$ is always finite. 

Comment: @Misha: pls post this as an answer.

Comment: @Marc: stankewicz already wrote this as an answer, so I hope it will suffice. 

Answer (score 1):

How about $\Gamma = PSL_2(\mathbf{Z})$, where $N(\Gamma)/\Gamma)$ is the trivial group but the automorphism group of $\Gamma \setminus \mathcal{H}^*$ is infinite?

In general the best you can do is that you have a map $N(\Gamma) \to \mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma \setminus \mathcal{H}^*)$ whose kernel is $\Gamma$. If you have no cusps, then you can say something else.

Comment: D'oh! Sorry Misha, completely didn't see your answer. I will gladly make this answer CW if requested.